# Limit the Outbound Data Transfer of a Video in a Given Timespan

Tags: azure, video, azure-media-services

I've started publishing videos using Azure Media Services.

The cost of experimenting is reasonable. To start I've added one 30 second video. If nobody watches it, this will cost less than a penny per month. If it receives 1300 monthly views, it will cost only $1.00/month.

My concern is a malicious user who might rack up views. That could cost a fortune in outbound data transfer fees.

So, I need to limit views. I would like a data transfer limit that is both per video and per time frame. For instance, I would like to limit each video to 10 views per hour.

I'm afraid a simple spending limit won't work, because my Azure account hosts other services. Those may need to scale beyond the outbound limit for a video.

Answer (score 1):

You can tryout archive your scenario with Azure Media Services Content protection functionality. 
Before user playback video it will get JWT token and video will be configured to use token authentication. Only logged in user or user who get token by solving some simple challenge (captcha or promo code) will be able to watch your video.

[Pricing](http://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/pricing/details/media-services/) is $0.10 per delivered 100 keys. 1300 monthly users will cost you $1.30. 
With JWT token you can cofigure token expiration and have additional logic in your app in regards who will be able to get new JWT token.

Code samples how to configure  token authentication can be found in https://github.com/Azure/azure-media-services-samples/tree/master/KDWithADMVC or you can also looked into tests associated with JWT usage in [Azure Media services .NET SDK repository](https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-media-services/blob/dev/test/net/Scenario/DynamicEncryption/GetKeyDeliveryUrlTests.cs) (See GetHlsKeyDeliveryUrlAndFetchKeyWithJWTAuthentication test)